# GUI development for my c application . How to proceed?

Tags: python, c, user-interface, wxpython, tkinter

I have developed an application in C which works on command line interface. I want to make my code display data over GUI, and I would also want to provide a window waiting for user input.

I need some directions on how to proceed. I came across a few sites saying libraries in python will serve the purpose.: WxPython, TKinter, PyQt

How to start abt? How do I link my C application to the GUI? And should I develop a GUI application, too, and then link it to my C application?

I am a beginner. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You said your application is written in C, but you did not tag your question as such.

Comment: Do you basically want to run your command line app from the GUI? If so, **[one of my old answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927821/cookbook-gui-interface-for-a-command-line-script/9928345#9928345)** may be of use to you.

Comment: actually i need a gui front end for getting an input from the user .Based on that input my c program must work & the behaviour of the c program will vary based on the input given at any time. and finally my output from the c program must be displayed in a gui window .

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using **[GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)** or [**Qt**](http://qt.digia.com/) for your application.
They are popular, cross-platform and both have extensive documentation and great community.

Comment: To be fair, I've never used GTK, but I can give my full recommendation to Qt.  It's pretty easy to pick up for basic features, and has support for multiple languages.

Comment: I agree with the Qt recommendation.  It would be possible to write a GUI in Python (which uses wxPython / TKinter/ PyQt) and have it invoke your C code, but it's also an extra layer of complexity that's not needed.  As a beginner, I'd recommend the shortest route which would be using Qt from your C program.

Comment: @jason viers : but Qt is written in c++ right?? how to incorporate that in my c program?? thanks

Comment: actually i need a gui front end for getting an input from the user .Based on that input my c program must work & the behaviour of the c program will vary based on the input given at any time. and finally my output from the c program must be displayed in a gui window .

Comment: I'd heard of C bindings for Qt, but after digging a bit, it appears that GTK+ would a better way to go for C.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface

Comment: @JagStyle You can't incorporate Qt in your C program, but you can do it the other way around easily -- incorporate your C code into a Qt application.

Comment: ihave taken up glade3 with gtk+ for extending GUI support for my CLI c application finally.. i am working on it..  i feel its a bit easier so far..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cython](http://cython.org/) for easily connecting the C world with the Python world if you decide to link your C code with the UI, it's highly convenient as a glue language.

Depending on your application, it might be a good option to keep it as a command line application that you call from a python program. The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is the usual route here, but there are some tools that can help even more -- like [commandwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/commandwrapper).

As for the GUI, apart from the already mentioned (perfectly viable) alternatives in other answers, [Kivy](http://kivy.org) is an interesting newcomer, and [pyFLTK](http://pyfltk.sourceforge.net/) is a lightweight, easy-to-learn, old-school approach. These are a bit exotic, but it's good to know they exist.

Finally, [QT5](http://qt-project.org/qt5) was recently released and it shows a lot of promise. You might want to consider it if you don't mind writing C++, it's various language wrappers are not ready yet.

Comment: thanks toni, i read in google saying tcl/tk is easier for a begginner to interface a c program to a GUI application. can u guide me on this.

Comment: and i want to know if i should create a IPC for communicating between my GUI application and the c program for taking data from the GUI app and displaying it in GUI window???

Comment: and what u feel abt using python 's tkinter for developing the GUI and subprocess for linking my c application with the python script ????

Comment: It would probably be best to quickly try out a couple of different GUI toolkits and see which one suits you best personally. I've heard the same thing about TkInter but I've never used it myself (I went with wxpython many years ago). If you need IPC that simple subprocess pipes can't provide elegantly it's probably better to go with cython and linking with your C code.

Comment: ruza : actually i need a gui front end for getting an input from the user .Based on that input my c program must work & the behaviour of the c program will vary based on the input given at any time. and finally my output from the c program must be displayed in a gui window . SHOULD I REQUIRE A SEPERATE IPC FOR THIS PURPOSE?? or THE SUBPROCESS MODULE OF PYTHON WOULD SUFFICE ??

Comment: @JagStyle It sounds like you could take care of this communication by piping together the input and output streams of the two processes. One stream would transfer the user input to c program and the other would transfer data back to be displayed on the GUI. If you think this is doable go with subprocess and pipes for IPC, otherwise I would recommend cython. Different (more complex) kind of IPC would probably be an overkill in this case, and more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: SCANF BEHAVIOUR & INPUT STREAM consuming avoiding loop when a character is pressed while we wait for integer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935558/why-does-scanf-appear-to-skip-input

Comment: RESOLVING SEGMENTAION FAULTS - SIGNALS                      http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/resolving-crashes-and-segmentation-faults/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the libraries for whichever GUI framework you want to use.  [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) is available for C, as well as Python, so you don't really need to link to the Python library.  Other options (as indicated by Intelis) are [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) and [QT](http://qt.digia.com/).

If you're developing in Windows, then you may also use the Windows API to create your GUI application.  Alternatively, you might consider using C++ (Either managed C++ or [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).

Once you have installed the appropriate libraries, you will need to include them in your C source by using the `#include <...>` directive.

Take a look at these sites:

[WxWidgets Tutorial](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm).

[GTK+ Tutorials](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/)

[QT Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/)

Comment: thanks Jason , for a beginner which is easier to learn?? python - tkinter or the tcl/tk for developing a GUI application

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to capture the output of a C program using a GUI front-end.  If this is the case, then using Python is an acceptable choice, but for simplicity and maintainability, I would recommend incorporating your GUI front-end into your C program, if possible.  Otherwise, I would recommend looking through some documentation and sample codes for everything before you settle on something.  I can't really say which would be easier for you, as everyone has a different programming style and finds ease and struggles in different areas.

Comment: actually i need a gui front end for getting an input from the user .Based on that input my c program must work & the behaviour of the c program will vary based on the input given at any time. and finally my output from the c program must be displayed in a gui window .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798736/inserting-newlines-into-a-gtktextview-widget-gtk-programming